# Sharepoint 2013 Form validation - I have 4 date fields I want to validate on. The first 2 are compulsory second 2 can be blank or filled in

Tags: validation, calculated-column-formula

I am having dificulty getting my validation formular to work.

Field Names:

DateAdded (first date) Expectedleave (second date) these are compulsory and the Expectedleave must be equal to or greater than the date DateAdded.

Second two dates and where I am getting the problem

Timetoleave (this must be equal to or greater than the Dateadded)

DateDischarged (This must be equal to or greater than the Timetoleave -  but should ONLY be able to be entered if the Timetoleave has a date entered)

This is what I have currently:

```
=AND((AND([Expectedleave]>=[DateAdded])),(OR([Timetoleave]="",[Timetoleave]>=[DateAdded])),(OR([DateDischarged]="",[DateDischarged]>=[Timetoleave])))
```

However if the Timetoleave is kept blank I can still enter a DateDischarged.

I DO NOT want to be able to confirm a DateDischarged without a Timetoleave being entered.